# Is there any real disadvantage in building all libraries with profiling enabled?

Tags: haskell, profiling, ghc, cabal

Given [how laborious it is to enable profiling later](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12048352/1333025), is there any real disadvantage (except more disk space used) in building all libraries with profiling enabled by default? In particular, are there any disadvantages for development, once all libraries with profiling enabled are installed?

Answer (score 7):

The disadvantages are:

- longer compile times (> 2x slower to build two or more copies of the libraries)
- increased installer sizes (> 2x larger)

Advantages are:

- you can profile when you need to profile without rebuilding the world.

Comment: Which is why the first thing I do after installing `haskell-platform-prof` is turn on library profiling in my cabal configuration.

Comment: In particular, neither of these disadvantages apply to development, once everything is installed.